# PHP switch statement that calls multiple functions; all function outputs are being returned instead of one

Tags: php

I have a PHP switch statement that either grants access to a form or displays an error message based on the type of user and whether he/she has rights to it. The case I need help with looks like this:

```
case 2:
CheckStatus();
CheckRevokeFlag();
CheckNotifyFlag();
RecordLock();
include 'gotopage1.php';
break;
```

The function calls display messages based on the level of the user's access. My problem is that ONLY ONE message should ever display at a time, but sometimes more than one condition can be true. For example, if the user does not have rights to the form (CheckStatus) AND the form is also in use by someone else (RecordLock), then he gets both "access denied" and "record is locked." Is there a way to fix this so that the user only gets either the "access denied" message or the "record is locked" message, or should I use something other than a switch statement?

Comment: yes there is, but we know nothing of hoy your error messages are returned or displayed. do you want the first error? - then stop checking for more, or the last error? - then just overwrite $error

Comment: If any of those functions return a value you can test for to indicate an error has occurred you could prematurely `break;` out of the switch before you normally would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to take a shot in the dark here.

Let's say your functions are defined on this pattern:

```
function funcName() {
    // do some stuff here
    if( $error) echo $error;
}
```

Change it to this:

```
function funcName() {
    // do some stuff here
    if( $error) {
        echo $error;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now the function returns something, so we can do stuff with it. Change your `switch` case structure to:

```
case 2:
    CheckStatus() or break;
    CheckRevokeFlag() or break;
    CheckNotifyFlag() or break;
    RecordLock() or break;
    include "gotopage1.php";
    break;
```

So now, if each function returns `true` (ie has no error condition to report) then it will continue as normal. Otherwise, it will hit the `or break` and stop processing the remaining checks.

Comment: creative implementation. +1 for doing it without conditional blocks.

Comment: Hey Niet...just using this other question to reach you...I wasn't console.logging `this`....I was console.logging `this.tagname` which is a typo as it should be `this.tagName`...that was the problem. So I deleted the question. Thanks for the answer but it turned out not to be applicable!

Comment: @Aerovistae Well, even though you had a typo, you still brought up an interesting point and I really don't think those commenters should have shot you down the way they did. If they'd applied minimal thought... I just whipped open the console and typed in your code. Sure enough, `undefined` cropped up more than once. I then identified it, and saw that the relevant tag had no `href`. Really, the question was intersting, and it's a shame people won't take the time to lift a finger to help, just because you didn't give a "self-contained example" for such a simple piece of code...

Comment: Well, alright, I'll undelete if I can find it, you've convinced me.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: Much obliged, this solution set me right.